# Mangopay implementation for zf2

Tags: zend-framework2, payment-processing, mangopay

I'm looking for a vendor/module that implements mangopay functionality into zf2.
Has anyone done this before or know someone who can do it?

I espially need e-wallet and adaptive payment functionality.

Answer (score 1):

My team and I used https://github.com/MangoPay/mangopay2-php-sdk with success on a ZF2 project (I don't know if I can name it here without being perceived as advertisement and/or url bombing, but you can contact me for further details).

Pro tips:

- Do not use the library directly in your business code, always wrap calls to this API into a dedicated service. Create a `Wallet` service with business-related methods (`public function createUser(User $user)`, `public function createCardRegistration(User $user, Card $creditCard)`, ...)
- Be careful to properly read MangoPay api reference (https://docs.mangopay.com/api-references/) before you begin to use any feature, every detail is important and a missed sentence can rapidly become a headache
- Don't be afraid to contact the support team (https://www.mangopay.com/contact/ with a `technical` case type) when you're blocked. They're fast and can unlock an apparently blocked situation in minutes.
- Log everything, too much log is better than no log when it comes to payment. Play with log levels if you can't handle this much log :)